# Can't get ui-router display views under header app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm just getting started with ui-router and can't make it displaying a view under the ui-view template.

Main template looks like this

index.html

```
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
  <link href="stylesheets/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<h4>
    This should be the header
</h4>
<div ui-view></div>

<script src="vendor/angular.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

test.html contains just few lines of text

app.js

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.router'])
    .config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('main', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'views/test.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
          });
  })
```

And on the '/' page I can only see a header and no test.html text.Console gives no errors.
What am I missing here?

Comment: could you provide plunker for this code? from the first look, seems correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EHOzeDkYPeDg5tR52RIz?p=preview), which shows, that we should **not** forget to set the default route via the: **`$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");`**. So the only extension made is the injection of `$urlRouterProvider` and configuration what to do at the start-up *(otherwise)*:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

    $stateProvider
        .state('main', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'test.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
          });
})
```

See that [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/EHOzeDkYPeDg5tR52RIz?p=preview) in action.

NOTE: also, do not mix usage of ui-router and default angular routing:

```
<script src="vendor/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<!--<script src="vendor/angular-route.js"></script>-->
```

Simply use one, or the other. The `ui-router`, *which you've already started to use*, would/should be good enough...

Comment: I've copied everything from my nodejs directory to a plunker and it works great, but it still doesn't work on my computer. I'll try to start all over again from scratch.

Comment: It could be really some very simple *wrong* setting... but do not give up, please. Ui-router is really great tool, and it will help you later a lot, I am sure...;)